# Wordpress slider with multiple images

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, slider

I'm not sure if im searching for the wrong thing, but I'm after a wordpress plugin that creates an image slider/carousel that shows more than one image at a time. So the slider would, for example, show two images. Then you'd be able to click the next or previous, and it would automatically aline to the left/right with the next/previous image.

So the thing would slide left or right showing the next/previous images.

I know I've seen these around a lot, but cant seem to find one now - only sliders that show only one image at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just thought I'd let everyone now what I ended up using.

I used "http://simple-fields.com/" plugin to add some new custom fields for the slider
then "http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/" for my carousel. CarouFredsel is awesome and very versatile.

I probably could have used jcarousel as mentioned by ink.robot but was familiar with fred!

cheers

Answer (score 2):

jCarousel for wordpress is one such plugin. The CSS is easy enough to modify to display n-number of images, not just one, two etc.

Find it here:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jcarousel-for-wordpress/

Note that it's not been updated for wordpress for a while now, but should still work just fine.